# Convergence in probability of a random sample

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2$,... be iid random variables and $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$. I need to prove if $S_n/n$ converges in probability to 0, then $M_n/n$ also converges in probability to $0$, where $M_n$ is maximum of $S_1,...S_n$.

My attempt : I tried to find a connection with Etemadi's or similar tools in maximal inequality things. But I have no idea on which one I should choose. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure if you willing to assume anything else about the $X_i's$, but if $E(X_i)=0$, this follows from the strong law of large numbers, and the basic fact that if $a_n$ is a sequence of real numbers, then $a_n = o(n)$ if and only if $\max_{1\le j \le n } |a_j| = o(n)$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But, no restriction on expectations or variances here.

Comment: Don't know if you tried, but Ottaviani's inequality may be useful here: for any $m<n,$ $\epsilon>0$,
$$P\left(\max_{m<k\le n} |S_{m,k}|>2\epsilon\right)\le \frac{P\left(|S_{m,n}|>\epsilon\right)}{\displaystyle{\min_{m<j\le n}}P\left(|S_{j,n}|\le \epsilon \right)},$$
where $S_{m,n}=S_n-S_m=X_{m+1}+\dots +X_n.$ Setting $\epsilon n$ for $\epsilon$ and $m=0$, we get 
$$P\left(\left|\max_{0<k\le n} S_{k}\right|>2\epsilon n\right)\le P\left(\max_{0<k\le n} |S_{k}|>2\epsilon n\right)\le \frac{P\left(|S_{n}|>\epsilon n\right)}{\displaystyle{\min_{0<j\le n}}P\left(|S_{j,n}|\le \epsilon n \right)}.$$

Comment: The numerator of the RHS goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ by assumption and thus the problem boils down to proving $\min_{0<j\le n}P\left(|S_{j,n}|\le \epsilon n \right)>0$ as $n\to\infty$. But currently, I don't have any ideas to show that unfortunately, not even sure if the result follows from this inequality but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!